# In $S_9$: for given $\sigma$ is there $\tau$ with $\tau^2=\sigma, \; \tau^3 = \sigma$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Struggling with these:

Let $\sigma$ in $S_9$ be given by $\sigma=(8\,9)(5\,6\,7\,1\,2\,3\,4)$.

1: Is there a $\tau\in S_9$ with $\tau^2=\sigma\,?\;$ *Tip*: think of $ \epsilon ( \sigma)$.

2: Is there a $\tau\in \langle\sigma \rangle$ with $\tau^3=\sigma\,?\;$ *Tip*: think of $ \operatorname{order}( \sigma)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, have you thought about $\epsilon(\sigma)$ and $\operatorname{order}(\sigma)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the tips you were given.

What is $\epsilon(\sigma)$? What do you know about $\epsilon$? Can you use what you know about $\epsilon$ to find such a $\tau,$ or prove that no such $\tau$ exists? (**Edit**: Nice work!)

What is the order of $\sigma$? What then do you know about the structure of the group $\langle\sigma\rangle$? Can you then find such a $\tau$?

Comment: For the first one I thought: $\sigma = (89)(5671234)=(89)(54)(53)(52)(51)(57)(56)$. So $\epsilon ( \sigma) = -1^7=-1$. For $\tau ^2$ we have $\epsilon ( \tau^2) =(\epsilon ( \tau))^2 = 1 $. So there is no $\tau$.

Comment: Perfect! Right on target. What have you been able to get for the second part?

Comment: order(σ)=|⟨σ⟩|=14. But I dont understand how to continue with Lagrange.

Comment: If there is such a $\tau,$ then since $\tau\in\langle\sigma\rangle,$ then $\tau=\sigma^k$ for some integer $0\le k\le 13$. Since $\tau^3=\sigma,$ then $\sigma^{3k}=\sigma,$ so $\sigma^{3k-1}$ is the identity permutation. Since the order of $\sigma$ is $14,$ what can we say about the relationship between $14$ and $3k-1$? Is this possible for the choices of $k$ available to us? For which $k$?

Comment: This makes it really easy, k=5, it's obvious now! thanks :)

Comment: No problem, Roman!

Answer (score 5):

1. Perhaps you are more familiar with the notation $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$? $\epsilon(\sigma)$ is a more general notation which is sometimes used to denote the sign of a permutation. What is the sign of $\sigma$? Is it an even, or odd permutation? What can you conclude about the existence then, (or **lack thereof**), of a permutation $\tau$ such that $\tau^2 =\sigma$? 
   Edit: I just saw the follow-up comment, and your understanding, conclusions, and argument, about $(1)$ is *spot on*! (I think you understand more than your original post suggests you do.)
2. Recall that $\operatorname{order}(\sigma) = |\langle \sigma\rangle|$, that is, it is equal to the order of the cyclic group generated by $\sigma$. The *order* of a permutation that is expressed as the product of disjoint cycles is equal to the *least common multiple* ("lcm") of the lengths of its cycles. 
    So what is $\operatorname{order}(\sigma) = \operatorname{lcm}(2, 7)\,?\;$ Use this information to argue that **exactly one such** $\tau \in \langle\sigma\rangle$ exists such that $\tau^3 = \sigma$. 
   **Edit**: You've correctly found that the order of $\sigma = 14$. So $\sigma^{14} = \text{id} \implies \sigma^{15} = (\sigma^5)^3 = \sigma$. So we simply put $\;\bf \tau = \sigma^5 \implies \tau^3 = (\sigma^5)^3 = \sigma$

Comment: $\operatorname{order}(\sigma) = |\langle \sigma\rangle|=14$. But I dont understand how to continue with Lagrange.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you've got the correct order. All you need to note is that $3$ and $14$ are relatively prime. The elements in $\langle \sigma \rangle$ can have order of $1$, the identity, order of 2, or order of $7$, or order $14$ (by Lagrange). So can $\tau^3$, with the order of $\tau$ being either 1, 2, or 7, every equal $\sigma$ whose order is $14$?

Comment: Actually, such a $\tau$ *does* exist (*exactly* one such, in fact), unless I'm doing something wrong in my reasoning.

Comment: Did you find the tau you needed? ;-)

Comment: @Cameron, yes, indeed such a $\tau$ exists (**you, like me, initially ruled it out**,  then you, like I, realized such a $\tau$ does exist.

Comment: +1: Yep! I felt like a n00b when I realized "Oh, right...$14$ divides itself." /facepalm/

Comment: @amWhy: deserves another TU +1